# Passing a string to pandas.loc

Tags: python, pandas, string

There is a pandas data frame for which it is required make a subset using multiple conditions. This works when the conditions are hard-coded:

```
subset_frame = data_frame.loc[(data_frame['Quantity'] >5) & (data_frame['Discount'] >0)]
```

The conditions vary and a function is being created for whatever list of conditions is supplied. A string is produced by the function:

```
mystring = "(data_frame['Quantity'] >5) & (data_frame['Discount'] >0)"
```

This is fed into .loc:

```
subset_frame= data_frame.loc[mystring]
```

Which returns an error:

```
KeyError: "(data_frame['Quantity'] >5) & (data_frame['Discount'] >0)"
```

As per first example with subset_frame above, this exact text, copied from the KeyError output and pasted/hard-coded into .loc, runs successfully.

A different method, .update, has also been attempted:

```
data_frame.update(data_frame.loc[mystring])
```

This returns the same error.

What is the mistake in my code or my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) :

```
mystring = "(data_frame['Quantity'] >5) & (data_frame['Discount'] >0)"

subset_frame= data_frame.loc[eval(mystring)]
```

Comment: Works thank you. I'll accept answer when SO allows.